# Create a callback function for uploading file

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using parse-php-sdk. I try to upload a file larger than 2 mb, I get this error:

```
Cannot retrieve data for unsaved ParseFile.
```

It works when filesize is smaller than 2 mb . So I‌ need to Create a callback function for uploading file in my code.
How should I do it?

```
                    $File_name = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
                    $File_data = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];

                    $Parse_File = ParseFile::createFromFile($File_data,$File_name);
                    $Parse_File->save(true);

                    $ParseObject = new ParseObject("Files");
                    $ParseObject->set("Title",$Title);
                    $ParseObject->set("Description",$Description);
                    $ParseObject->set("File",$Parse_File);

                    $ParseObject->save(true);
```

Comment: How are you hosting your parse server? Do you have any revere proxy on top of it?